# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$sql' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ravi\search.php on line 16

Tags: php

(1) first file is fill.php and i am using a second file search.php, i pass parameters from fill.php to search.php , but i am getting an error i am getting unexpected t_variable error in line 16 in search.php

### fill.php

```
<?php
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="search.php" method="post">

   <table style="color:purple;border-style:groove; height:150px;width:350px" >
            <tr>
                <td style=" height:25px; font-family:'Copperplate Gothic 
Bold'">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:red;background-color:aqua;height:25px">Enter Employee id&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input name="name" id="name" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height:25px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="color:white;background-color:brown; height:30px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Search.php

```
 <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if (!$con)
         {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }
          mysql_select_db("ravi", $con);
          $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
          if (!$con)
           {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
           }
           mysql_select_db("mysql", $con);
           $name = (int)$_post['name']
           $sql = "SELECT * from empmast where empid= $name";
           $result = mysql_query($sql);
           if (!$result)
            {
               die("Error running $sql: " . mysql_error());
             }
            while($rowval = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                   $empid= $rowval['empid'];
                   $empname= $rowval['empname'];
                 }
                 mysql_close($con);

         ?>
```

Comment: Missing `;` on the previous line

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_ because it's deprecated. Use mysqli_ or PDO.

Comment: I agree with @Edward use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

In your search.php file, you are missing a `;` semicolon on line 15.

```
$name = (int)$_POST['name']
```

should be

```
$name = (int)$_POST['name'];
```

You should also stop using `mysql_`. [Here's why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Use `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: @ravi This is the correct answer. But you should learn about debugging before just posting on stack. This is a very simple error to debug. Do you use an IDE to write your scripts? I suggest PHP Storm or Komodo.

Comment: @Edward Nice name :). Agreed. I use Sublime Text with SublimeLinter with SublimeLinter-php. You could also use PHP Storm.

Comment: :) i hope @ravi is taking notes...